# Functions involving real values

Tags: functions

If $f$ is a real valued differentiable function satisfying

$|f(x)-f(y)|<(x-y)^2$ for all real $x$ and $y$

and $f(0)=0$

then $f(1)$ equals:

Comment: The inequality must be inclusive i.e. $\,\le\,$ instead of $\,\lt\,$ otherwise it can never be satisfied for $\,x=y\,$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First you don't need the assumption differentiability. You can prove that $f' =0$ (use definition of differentiability). This shows $f$ is constant, and then $f(1) = f(0)=0$

Answer (score -2):

We can simpify it as f(x)-f(y)/x-y= x-y
If we take that x approaches to y it implies that derivative of f is zero 
Since f'(x)= f(x)-f(y)/x-y
Now, if f'(x) is zero then we can say f is a constant function since derivative of a constant function is zero. 
It implies f(0)=f(1)=0

Comment: The question asks about "$\lt$" (which should actually be "$\le$" per my other comment), while your posted answer refers to "$=$" which is quite different.

Comment: Yes it consists of = also.

Comment: I regret for it.

Comment: You can always edit your original question to make any clarifications or additions. As to this answer, it is wrong as it stands now. In particular `We can simpify it as f(x)-f(y)/x-y= x-y` does not follow from the premises of the question. Take a look at the answers to the duplicate question for the correct approach.